# ERROR 1290: the mysql server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: mysql

[image: ERROR 1290]
Trato de crear un nuevo usuario para la base de datos pero me arroja el error de la imagen.

Comment: Reinicia mysql y el error debe desaparecer.

Comment: ya lo reinicie y me da el sig. mysql> ERROR 1045 (28000): Acces denied for user 'armuars'@'%' (using password: YES)